# How to check if a point P(x,y) lies inside a thick line?

Tags: geometry

I have line whose end points p1 and p2 coordinates I know.
The line has a width w (basically it forms a rectangle)

How to check if a point P(x,y) lies inside this line.

What I tried was taking perpendicular distance from P to the line and check if its less than half the width.

But this will allow those points that are outside the rectangle and near to either p1 or p2.

[image]

In this image , say C is to the right of B with perpendicular distance less than half the width , then also its accepted.

How do I handle this case where the perpendicular distance is less than half the width but the point doesn't lie inside the rectangle formed between the two points A and B ?

In the shown figure below , how do I find the location of D , so that i can then see if it lies between the line segment(which i know how to do) ?

Comment: This is pretty simple.  As you said, you are interested in a rectangle not a line.  Googling "check if a point is inside a polygon" will get you the answer.

Comment: See [How to check if a point is inside a rectangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/190111) or [Check if a general point is inside a given cylinder](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518495)

Comment: Please do not use tags whose meaning you don't know!

Answer (score 1):

Let the line segment endpoints be $\vec{p}_0 = (x_0 , y_0)$ (A in OP's diagram) and $\vec{p}_1 = (x_1 , y_1)$ (B in OP's diagram), and the point to be tested $\vec{p} = (x, y)$ (C in OP's diagram).

First, calculate
$$t = \frac{(\vec{p} - \vec{p}_0)\cdot(\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0)}{(\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0)\cdot(\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0)} = \frac{ (x - x_0)(x_1 - x_0) + (y - y_0)(y_1 - y_0) }{ (x_1 - x_0)^2 + (y_1 - y_0)^2 } \tag{1}\label{AC1}$$
If $0 \le t \le 1$, the point on the line (D in OP's diagram) closest to the point to be tested (C in OP's diagram) is between the line segment endpoints.

Then, calculate the distance squared between the point to be tested $\vec{p}$, and the point on the line segment closest to that point:
$$d^2 = \left\lVert \vec{p} - \bigr( (1 - t)\vec{p}_0 + t \vec{p}_1 \bigr)\right\rVert^2 = \bigr( x - x_0 - t ( x_1 - x_0) \bigr )^2 + \bigr( y - y_0 - t ( y_1 - y_0 ) \bigr )^2 \tag{2}\label{AC2}$$
If the total line thickness is $w$, the point to be tested $\vec{p}$ is on the line if
$$d^2 \le \left(\frac{w}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4} w^2$$

In other words, if and only if
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
0 \le & t \le 1 \\
~ & d^2 \le \frac{1}{4} w^2 \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{3}\label{AC3}$$
is the point $\vec{p}$ (point C in OP's diagram) within the "line segment" between $\vec{p}_0$ and $\vec{p}_1$, thickness $w$, and butt caps.

---

How did we do the above, and why?

First, we parametrise the location of the point D in OP's diagram, $\vec{p}_d = (x_d , y_d)$, as linear interpolation between $\vec{p}_0$ and $\vec{p}_1$:
$$\vec{p}_d(t) = (1 - t) \vec{p}_0 + t \vec{p}_1 = \vec{p}_0 + t (\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0) \tag{A}\label{A}$$
Here, $\vec{p}_d$ is a vector-valued function of parameter $t$, with $\vec{p}_d(0) = \vec{p}_0$ and $\vec{p}_d(1) = \vec{p}_1$. If $0 \le t \le 1$, $\vec{p}_d(t)$ is within the line segment endpoints, otherwise it is elsewhere on the extended line.

Point $\vec{p}_d(t)$ is closest to $\vec{p}$ when their distance is minimized, or when the vector between them is perpendicular to the vector between the line segments.  The former occurs when the derivative of the distance or distance squared is zero; the latter is much easier.  That is, the line between $\vec{p}_d(t)$ and $\vec{p}$ is perpendicular to the line between $\vec{p}_0$ and $\vec{p}_1$ if and only if
$$\left(\vec{p}_d(t) - \vec{p}\right) \cdot \left(\vec{p}_0 - \vec{p}_1\right) = 0 \tag{B1}\label{B1}$$
which in Cartesian coordinate form is equivalent to
$$(x_0 + t (x_1 - x_0) - x)(x_1 - x_0) + (y_0 + t (y_1 - y_0) - y)(y_1 - y_0) = 0 \tag{B2}\label{B2}$$
To solve this for $t$, we simplify and rearrange it to
$$t \bigr( (x_1 - x_0)(x_1 - x_0) + (y_1 - y_0)(y_1 - y_0)\bigr) - (x - x_0)(x_1 - x_0) - (y - y_0)(y_1 - y_0) = 0$$
and finally to
$$t = \frac{ (x - x_0)(x_1 - x_0) + (y - y_0)(y_1 - y_0) }{ (x_1 - x_0)^2 + (y_1 - y_0)^2 } \tag{C}\label{C}$$
This is equivalent to the first equation in this answer, $\eqref{AC1}$, and tells us where the point on the line closest to $\vec{p}$ is.
It is between the line endpoints if and only if $0 \le t \le 1$.

Next, we need to find the distance between the point at hand, $\vec{p}$, and this closest point on the line $\vec{p}_d(t)$.  [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), i.e. $\left\lVert \vec{v} \right\rVert = \sqrt{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}}$, does perfectly.

However, because square root is a monotonically increasing function of its argument, we can compare *squared distances* instead of *distances*.  Mathematically, given $0 \le L \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 \le S \in \mathbb{R}$ (both $L$ and $S$ are nonnegative real numbers),
$$\begin{array}{cc}
L \lt S & \iff & L^2 \lt S^2 \\
L \le S & \iff & L^2 \le S^2 \\
L = S & \iff & L^2 = S^2 \\
L \ge S & \iff & L^2 \ge S^2 \\
L \gt S & \iff & L^2 \gt S^2 \\
\end{array}$$
This means that we can *always* compare squared distances instead of comparing distances.  Thus, we don't need to do the annoying square root operation, which is nice.

The Euclidean distance squared $d^2$ between $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{p}_d(t)$ is
$$d^2 = \bigr(\vec{p} - \vec{p}_d(t)\bigr)\cdot\bigr(\vec{p} - \vec{p}_d(t)\bigr)$$
which written in Cartesian coordinate form, using $\vec{p}_d(t) = \vec{p}_0 + t (\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_0) = (1 - t) \vec{p}_0 + t \vec{p}_1$, gives us the equation $\eqref{AC2}$ near the beginning of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible methods. Your method will work but requires another check. This is probably the simplest method.

1. Find D, the point on the line closest to C.
2. Check if D lies between A and B by comparing either $x$ or $y$ co-ordinates - ie. $x_A\le x_D \le x_B$ or $y_A \le y_C \le y_B$. There is no need to check both. If it does then go to step 3.
3. Calculate smallest distance CD of the point from the line.
4. Check if distance CD is less than or equal to the half-width of the rectangle.

Comment: how do i find D ? can u tell me the formula for it ?

Comment: @Nateshbhat https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation

Answer (score 0):

Translate `C` by `-A` and rotate it by the angle `-φ`, where `φ` is the orientation angle of `AB`.

Now check

```
0<x<W and |y|<H/2.
```